# not load image url in local json

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

HI This is an example of my json
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAHFT.png)

Gives me this error when using require for url
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDiyr.png)

Comment: Please do not post text as screenshots. Inline the text instead - it's much easier to read that way and works better with search engines, allowing other people to find this question in the future if they happen to have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use the require keyword in your image src attribute. Instead, simply add the object address. For example,

```
<img :src="BlogItem.img">
```

Try it, if it still gives error please share your folder structure and your codes in more details.

Comment: I remove require but it still does not work

Comment: Can you share the error, please?